# How to make universal iPhone/iPad app WITHOUT SHARING VIEWS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

I realize there are a lot of questions here about making universal apps, but not so much on how to make a universal app that has completely different views and functions. I would want the user to be able to download one app, but each version is completely different. Is the only way to do this to use if statements, sensing what device the user has, and then loading the correct view controllers from there (i.e. in the delegate, load the correct first view controller)?
Thanks

Comment: You should make sure this is allowable by Apple before you do it. Display/minor functionality changes between iPhone and iPad are expected, but if ex. the iPhone version was a clock app and the iPad version booked airline tickets, I don't know that Apple is going to approve this.

Comment: The two apps are the same idea, but they are different in the sense that it's not just a matter of resizing. They are fundamentally different in code, but functionality wise, they are very similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to **“deploy two different apps in a single binary”**. In case you already have two apps that don't share class names (or other top level object names), that should be pretty simple.

You should run device specific code **as soon as possible** and that is in `main.m`. **Pass different app delegate class for iPhone and for iPad.** The rest should work as normal and no classes from the other “device” should be used.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIUserInterfaceIdiom idiom = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom];
        Class appDelegateClass = Nil;
        if (idiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            appDelegateClass = [iPhoneAppDelegate class];
        }
        else if (idiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            appDelegateClass = [iPadAppDelegate class];
        }
        NSCAssert(appDelegateClass, @"Unexpected idiom! Maybe iWatch?");
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, appDelegateClass));
    }
}
```

You could also choose different *split point*, for example allocating different root view controller.

In case you want to share some code after all, you can just create universal superclasses, for example `iPhoneAppDelegate` and `iPadAppDelegate` can have superclass `AppDelegate` that handles notifications or URL handling.

Answer (score 2):

that is just the basic *universal* project's finish-launch method from the Apple:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

---

...but, you can load different view controllers for different interface idioms:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UIPhoneVersionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIPhoneVersionViewController" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UIPadVersionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIPadVersionViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

...and *violá*, job's done.

Comment: Note that if you name your XIB NameViewController~ipad.xib and NameViewController~iphone.xib XCode automatically use the correct Xib file.

Comment: @CedricSoubrie, yes, if that is the case, that can be useful as well.