# How to apply styling specific to device

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and I am creating an universal iOS application in which I want to apply some styling specific to device like iPhone or iPad. Right now I am having if conditions with logic every where in my code. How can I achieve this in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this efficiently by defining a macro and placing this macro in some common class in your application

Below snippet might help -

```
#define IsDeviceiPad() \
  ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before, I was creating an app that had one too many if statements. I, same as you thought that there must be an efficient way to program the app. I came across this answer:

[How to make universal iPhone/iPad app WITHOUT SHARING VIEWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302946/how-to-make-universal-iphone-ipad-app-without-sharing-views)

The key is to run device specific code **as soon as possible** and that is in `main.m`. **Pass different app delegate class for iPhone and for iPad**. The rest should work as normal and no classes from the other “device” should be used.

Best of luck.